# Memory Leak from Tags (Poolmon) FSTB and/or SCDG

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have a huge memory Leak (2GB+) happening from the first second I turn on the PC (Windows 7, 6GB RAM).

Poolmon points to two tags (the same amount of memory, however sometimes its the first and others the second): FSTB and SCDG.

I suspect a disk driver but cannot find what to change.

Any ideas?

Thank you,

IV

Answer (score 0):

Both are tags used by Microsoft drivers. In the `pooltag.txt` I see both listed:

```
Fstb - <unknown>    - ntos\fstub
ScDG - <unknown>    -      disk geometry buffer
```

Here you need to capture a grow of the pool usage with [xperf](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx). Open a cmd prompt (cmd.exe) as admin and run this:

```
xperf -on BASE+Pool –stackwalk PoolAlloc+PoolFree -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\trace_pool_alloc.etl
```

Now open it in [WPA.exe](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool#time=09m55s), [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx) and look for the tags under `AIFO` (*allocated insde freed outside*) and expend the stack. From the function names you may have any idea what is going on.